# sawtooth function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis

> Let $x \in\mathbb{R}$  $f(x)=\{ x\}$ be  fractional part function or sawtooth function.
>    and $F_x=\{f(n\ x);\ n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$
>
> Show that  $x\in\mathbb{Q}\Longleftrightarrow \ \exists\ q \in \mathbb{N}^* \mid\ f(q\ x)=0 $
>
> Let $x=\dfrac{p}{q};\ (p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}^{*},\ $Show that  : $\forall\ n\in\mathbb{N}^*\ : \ f(n\ x)=f(r\ x)\ $
>
> and deduce that  $F_x\ $ is finite (the number $r$ is to define)

all i can say that we've $\forall x \in Z \quad f(x)=0 \iff x$ is in the $Z$  therefore the elements $x$ for which there are $q\in N*$ such that $f(qx)=0$ are the elements of $Q$.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does your notation $f(n\ x)$ mean? $f$ of $n$ times $x$?

Comment: @RoryDaulton   yes means times

Comment: What about $x=\frac13, q=3$? Then $x \in \Bbb Q$, but $f(qx)=0$, no?

Comment: @DanielR  see my update

Comment: Ok, makes more sense. So, the questions are: Is my proof of the first "Show that..." correct, and how do I prove the second "Show that..."? Correct?

Comment: @DanielR yes that's right

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by $\forall n\in \Bbb N^\ast : f(nx)=f(rx)$. What is $r$? What do you mean by "the number $r$ is to define?"

Answer (score 0):

To make your argument a bit clearer, you could break the equivalence into impliciations and show that they hold in both directions.

For "$\Longrightarrow$", set $x=\dfrac r s \in \Bbb Q$ and use the fact that $s \in \Bbb N^\ast$ and $xs \in \Bbb Z$.

For "$\Longleftarrow$", you can conclude that $qx = n\in \Bbb Z$, which implies that $x = \dfrac n q \in \Bbb Q$.